# How to throttle network traffic for environment simulation?

Tags: networking, simulation, bandwidth, wireshark, trafficshaping

I'm trying to test an application that uses a database connection. What I would like to do is throttling the bandwith to, say, 1 MBit or such to get a better feeling for the application under realistic conditions.

I already use Wireshark to have a look at the communication with the DB and I expected Wireshark to have a feature like that but as it seems there is no way to do something like that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wireshark is primarily for monitoring, filtering, and recording network communications that are taking place, not preventing what can or cannot be sent out.

Comment: I don't think Wireshark has that...You could change your nic card's settings to only run at 10mbs...

Comment: @Josh: that sounds like what I'm looking for. But how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [WANem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/). You can download a bootable ISO that you boot up on any system with multiple NICs which you then insert between your client and server. It lets you control bandwidth, latency, jitter, loss, and a few other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[Trickle](http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/61293?tid=100&tid=47&tid=13)**. Also, if you are using a router, commercial-grade router firmware generally has some **[QoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service)** traffic-shaping services.

Comment: Right now, I'm testing on a windows machine and all tools and libs I find are only available an Linux. I also have to test on OS-level, so there is no real hardware involved that I could tweak. Probably there's some kind of extension for the WinPcap driver?

Answer (score 0):

If you can test it out at the endpoint you could try using a browser throttler.  One example is [Firefox Throttle](http://www.uselessapplications.com/en/Application/FirefoxThrottle.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, the program I'm testing does not have any kind of web frontend. It's just a Java Swing Application connected to a database. (For all kinds of web applications I've already used Firefox Throttle - nice tool, btw)

Answer (score 0):

A program called BWMeter can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your own router, see if there is a Bandwith control or Quality Of Service (QoS) section. That way you can limit all your outgoing/incoming traffic to whatever you want.

TP-LINK has this for example:
[image]