# iPhone Simulator - Simulate a slow connection?

Tags: iphone, networking, connection, ios-simulator, simulation

Is there a way to slow down the internet connection to the iPhone Simulator, so as to mimic how the App might react when you are in a slow spot on the cellular network?

Comment: Alan's answer should be accepted.

Comment: @StanislavMayorov this question is from 9 years ago. Alan then gave an updated answer 4 years later. It is now 5 years after that. Sorry I am not going through and reconsidering accepted answers on my old questions.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

An app called SpeedLimit

https://github.com/mschrag/speedlimit

Works great.

chris.

Comment: awesome just tried that out and it does the business. Thanks!

Comment: Yosemite: failed to set speed limit

Comment: Broken, it says `Failed to set speed limit`

Comment: The right way to do this is explained by [Alan H. answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27363671/3340702).

Comment: "I am no longer able to maintain this project. Please feel free to fork and take ownership."

Answer (score 322):

### How to install Apple’s Network Link Conditioner

*These instructions current as of October 2019.*

*Warning: If you just upgraded to new version of macOS, **make sure you install the very latest Network Conditioner** ([in Additional Tools for Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)) or it may [silently fail](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66042); that is, you will turn it on but it won’t throttle anything or drop any packets.*

*Update: **As of Xcode 11, there may be an even simpler way to simulate network conditions on tethered devices; see [this blog post](https://www.agnosticdev.com/content/how-test-network-link-conditioner-xcode-11)**. For how to affect **simulated** devices, continue below, as before.*

1. Install Xcode if you don’t have it.
2. Open Xcode and go to Xcode › Open Developer Tool › More Developer Tools…

[image: Screen shot of navigating the menu as described]

3. Download **Additional Tools for Xcode** (matching your current Xcode version)

[image: Additional IO Tools download link]

4. Open the downloaded disk image and double-click the Network Link Conditioner .prefpane under “Hardware” to install it.

[image: pref pane in DMG]

[image: system preferences showing installation prompt]

5. There we go!

[image: Screen shot of the preference pane]

6. Be sure to turn it on. You need to select a profile *and* enable the network conditioner.

[image]

### Caveat

This won't affect localhost, so be sure to use a staging server or co-worker's computer to simulate slow network connections to an API you’re running yourself. You may find https://ngrok.com/ helpful in this regard.

Comment: for Xcode 8, this is included in "Additional Tools for Xcode 8" (instead of "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode")

Comment: @MohitSingh Thanks. I have updated the answer above.

Comment: There seem to be no Additional Tools for Xcode 10.3?

Comment: @leo, just use the current Additional Tools for the major version of Xcode you have. For example, use *Additional Tools for Xcode 11* if you have *Xcode 11.1* installed.

Comment: Or, more accurately, use the latest available Additional Tools, up to the version of Xcode you have. For example, use *Additional Tools for Xcode 11* if you have *Xcode 11.1* installed, since currently there is no version specifically for 11.1.

Comment: for XCode 13.0 running on macOS Big Sur (11.6) you need to install Additional tools for Xcode 12.5 (instead of Additional tools for Xcode 13).

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690358?login=true&page=1#691824022

Comment: Network Link Conditioner of Additional Tools for Xcode 13.2 beta works well on Monterey on M1.

Answer (score 84):

"There's an app for that!" ;) Apple provides "Network Link Conditioner" preference pane that does the job quite well.

- for Xcode versions prior to 4.3, the pane installer can be found in your `Developer` folder, e.g. `"/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Network Link Conditioner"`, after installation, if daemon fails to start and you don't want to reboot your machine, just use  `sudo launchctl load /system/library/launchdaemons/com.apple.networklinkconditioner.plist`
- if you are already done with `Developer` folder, you can install the pane as a part of "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode" package available via Mac Dev Center additional downloads section.

Link to download page (you must log in with your Apple ID): https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action
(credits to @nverinaud)

Comment: Here is a link to browse available downloads : https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Comment: doesnt work on Mountain Lion ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414676/network-link-conditioner-seems-to-have-no-effect-on-network-behavior-on-lion-mo

Comment: would be nice if it were app specific, and not for the whole computer

Comment: You can download "Hardware IO Tools" from Apple's developer tools site now.  They update it for new releases of Xcode (and thus OSX): In Xcode, click `Xcode` -> `Open Developer Tool` -> `More Developer Tools...`, login, find the latest archive, download, copy the files somewhere, double click the Network Conditioner preference pane thingy, install it... yay!

Comment: I guess doesn't work for Yosemite. I set it to "lossy" but actually didn't get any difference

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Works fine with Yosemite (10.10.4).

Answer (score 18):

It also worth mentioning that Xcode also has a built in way for **devices**, not simulator.

- Just go 'Devices and Simulator' (`cmmd+shift+2`)
- Select your device
- Scroll down til you find 'Device Conditions'
- Set your desired profile
- Hit Start

[image]

To have this working you need to install 'Network Link Conditioner' on your Mac. See steps mention [in Alan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27363671/5175709)

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that a slow connection isn't enough to simulate real-work mobile data network behaviour - since there is also much more packet loss, higher latencies and more dropped connections too.

Here is a handy script I found to configure the firewall to emulate these parameters:

http://pmilosev-notes.blogspot.com/2011/02/ios-simulator-testing-over-different.html

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -ne "3" ]
then
    echo "Usage:\n$0 <bandwidth in kpbs> <delay in ms> <packet loss ratio>";
    exit 1
fi  

BW=$1
DELAY=$2
PLR=$3
sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw ${BW}Kbit/s delay $DELAY plr $PLR
sudo ipfw add 1 pipe 1 all from me to not me
sudo ipfw add 2 pipe 1 all from not me to me
echo "RETURN to stop connection noise"
read
sudo ipfw delete 1
sudo ipfw delete 2
exit 0
```

Some suggested values you can use:

| Scenario | Bw (Kbit) | delay (ms) | pr (ratio) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.5G mobile | (GPRS) | 50 | 200 |
| 3G mobile | 1000 | 200 | 0.2 |
| VSAT | 5000 | 500 | 0.2 |
| Busy LAN on VSAT | 300 | 500 | 0.4 |

Comment: Network Link Conditioner (tool from Apple that installs as a preference pane) simulates slow connections, packet loss, and latency.

Comment: Network Link Conditioner, added in OS X Lion (released in July 2011), makes scripts like this unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in really device through Xcode(14) settings

Debug -> Induce Device conditions -> Network Link -> select the Network you want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to emulate a slow connection, unlike, say, the nice network connection emulator that blackberry developers enjoy.  However, since your simulator's connection goes through your computer - you can simply focus on slowing down your computer's connection.

You'll want to achieve two things (depending upon your circumstances):

- throttle your bandwidth
- increase your latency

Maybe this will point you in right direction:

http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080119112509736

There are some good open source solutions, too, but I so can't remember their names.

This question might help: [How to throttle network traffic for environment simulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273839/how-to-throttle-network-traffic-for-environment-simulation)