# Network Link Conditioner seems to have no effect on network behavior on Lion, Mountain Lion

Tags: networking, io, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

The Network Link Conditioner preference pane (installed from the "[Hardware IO Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-)" DMG on the Apple developer site) doesn't appear to have any effect when turned on. The original author of this question reported the symptoms on Mountain Lion. A later editor experienced the same symptoms and lack of expected network behavior change on Lion, with Xcode 4.5.1 installed.

When enabled, /var/log/system.log shows:

```
Jan 17 17:36:14 matt-mmf-macbook [0x0-0x1d01d].com.apple.systempreferences[371]: System Preferences(371,0x10fac7000) malloc: *** auto malloc[371]: error: GC operation on unregistered thread. Thread registered implicitly. Break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() to debug.
Jan 17 17:36:18 matt-mmf-macbook System Preferences[371]: process command (simulate) failed
Jan 17 17:36:18 matt-mmf-macbook [0x0-0x1d01d].com.apple.systempreferences[371]: _nlc_start_simulation: (os/kern) failure
Jan 17 17:36:18 matt-mmf-macbook System Preferences[371]: Starting Network Link Conditioner
```

And the network connections do not exhibit the behavior specified by the selected profile.

Has anyone successfully gotten it to work, or figured out what the error in system.log might mean? As of 2013-01-17, the "accepted/correct" answer does not work for everyone experiencing the symptoms.

Comment: I have the same issues. Did anyone managed this?

Comment: If anyone's curious, there's now an Oct 2013 version of Hardware IO which seems to work on Mavericks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

i just had the same problem. Installed the Conditioner pane on Lion and after updating to Mountain Lion, it still was available in the settings pane, but had no effect when turned on.

i fixed that by just removing the Conditioner (right click in the settings pane -> Remove "Network...") and reinstalling it from the Hardware IO Tools Image (Late July 2012).

Hope it works too for you. i think the os x update must have overwritten something.

Comment: Thanks maaalex. I had tried that before, but this time I rebooted after uninstalling, and that did the trick.

Comment: I tried rebooting, reinstalling, etc.  This tool does not work for me on Lion.

Comment: This answer does not work for me. I see the symptoms described in the question on Lion, with Xcode 4.5.1 and Hardware IO Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012.

Comment: I'm running Xcode 4.5.2 and Harware IO Tools for Xcode - Jan 2013 and same issue for me.

Comment: On MacOS X 10.7.5: I installed the tool from the Hardware IO Tools Image. It has no effect.

Comment: From another question I just got this tip and it works !

uninstall pref pane, restart mac, install new perf pane, restart mac. only then it worked properly.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on OSX 10.9. Installed and restarted, still nothing.

Comment: The Network Link Conditioner had no effect for me either on Mavericks OSX 10.9.4. I removed it as @maaalex suggested from the Settings pane and then installed the latest version (at the moment "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode - June 2, 2004") and then it worked perfectly. No reboot needed. You can take the image from http://developer.apple.com/downloads

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this problem on Lion. None of the methods in here worked. I found another tool called SpeedLimit (it's a free preference pane) and it works fine. http://mschrag.github.io/